# Pandas: groupby / aggregation / sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have a *DataFrame* like that:

```
ID_client l   date  l   contact
--------------------------------------
1          2017/01/01      email
1          2017/01/02      mail
1          2017/01/03      email
1          .........
1          2017/06/06      sms 
2          ......          tel 
2                          tel 
3
.
etc      until 2017/31/31 etc
```

and I would like to have 2 DataFrames, the first only one line for year with the sum of each contact split in different columns and the last same per month:

1)

```
id l email l sms l tel l mail
----------------------------
1    40       20   30    50
2    20       30    40   50 
2  ........................
3 ..............etc
```

2)

```
id l date_month l email l sms l tel l email
--------------------------------------------------
1    2017/01      20       10    5    2
1    2017/02      ..............
.
2    2017/01   .............
2    2017/02  ................
.
etc
```

I tried

```
Df.set_index("date")
Df["contact"].resample("m")
```

Or

```
Df.groupby(df["date", "I'd_client"])[contact].Count
```

Or I tried to create another *dataframe*

```
df2=Df.groupby(df.index)
Df2=[["contact"]]
df2.apply(lambda x : x.count())
```

I tried :

```
Df.set_index("date") Df["contact"].resample("m")
```

Or

```
Df.groupby(df["date", "I'd_client"])[contact]. Count
```

Or I tried to create another *dataframe*

`df2=Df.groupby(df.index`) Df2=[["contact"]] df2.apply(lambda x : x.count())

But it didnt give me what I wanted!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post of the code you have done?

Comment: I tried :

Df.set_index("date") Df["contact"].resample("m")

Or

Df.groupby(df["date", "I'd_client"])[contact]. Count

Or I tried to create another dataframe

`df2=Df.groupby(df.index`) Df2=[["contact"]] df2.apply(lambda x : x.count())

But it didnt give me what I wanted